# Value from Math.random is causing problems when I call the function inside itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script is giving me problems. I've re written it several times but I'm missing something.

'questions' array refers to my objects. These objects are different questions with 'a' always being the correct answer.

The script works fine up to this point. The idea is to increment 'n' from 0 to scroll through my array, and provide the next question when a correct answer is clicked. 'x' is always the correct answer (it always holds 'a').

So I can increment 'n' just fine on correct guess; however, when I call the function 'a()' again, (after my alert 'hi' part), it is causing problems. I want to increment n, and call a() so I get the next question. Then I want to place the correct guess (x) in a random place (ie position 0, 1 or 2.)

Grateful for any help.

```
var questions = [q0,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7];

var n = 0;

function a(){
var y;
var z;

var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
if(x == 0){y = 1; z = 2}else if(x == 1){y = 0; z = 2}else{y = 0; z = 1}

$("#question_holder").text(questions[n].q);

    $(".answer_holder").eq(x).text(questions[n].a);
    $(".answer_holder").eq(y).text(questions[n].b);
    $(".answer_holder").eq(z).text(questions[n].c);


    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".answer_holder").eq(x).click(function(){
            alert("hi");
                        n++;
            a();

                     /*this area needs to get the next question by incrementing
                     n, then generate a different value to x, to place it
                     in a different position. which it does. however,
                     in subsequent questions, you can click the wrong answer as if
                     it's correct, ie not 'a' or 'x'.*/
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: why is $(document).ready(function(){ inside the a() function? It normally appears outside all functions (on global scope), so it runs when the page is loaded. This is where you register your event, you want it to run as early as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the $(document).ready() in the wrong place.  Try something like this (caveat: this is completely untested):

```
function setupQuestion(n) {
    var x,y,z;

    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
    if(x == 0){y = 1; z = 2}else if(x == 1){y = 0; z = 2}else{y = 0; z = 1}

    $("#question_holder").text(questions[n].q);

    $(".answer_holder").eq(x).text(questions[n].a).data('answer', 'a');
    $(".answer_holder").eq(y).text(questions[n].b).data('answer', 'b');
    $(".answer_holder").eq(z).text(questions[n].c).data('answer', 'c');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = 0;
    $('.answer_holder').click(function() {
        if ($(this).data('answer') === 'a') { // Or whatever is the correct answer
            n++;
            if (n < questions.length) {
                setupQuestion(n);
            } else {
                // Do something else, the test is finished
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
    setupQuestion(n);
});
```

Note that I am not comparing on the `text()` function but rather the `data()` function.  This is because the text as displayed to the user might be decorated in some way, making comparisons difficult.  Simply using the answer index 'a' 'b' or 'c' is clearer.

Comment: I also changed the function name from "a" (non-descriptive) to "setupQuestion()" (more descriptive).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give this a try if I can't fix my original code.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is a bit strange here.. what you are trying to do is register a new click event every time a() runs. I think you want to register **one** click event for all `answer_holder` elements, and in the event handler check which element this is and handle it accordingly

Notice the following:

`$(document).ready(function(){` - the function defined in this handler is supposed to run once your page is loaded.. I don't think you want to use it inside a(). It is usually only used in global scope (outside all functions)

`$(".answer_holder").eq(x).click(function(){` - this event handler registers your function depending on the value of `x`. I suggest you register an event handler for all `$(".answer_holder")`, without depending on `x` (in the global scope). And inside that event handler (in the function), you check which element triggered the event (using `$(this)` - it returns the element that was clicked)

Comment: Is this really an answer or just pointing out some of the problems with OP's code?

Comment: he is asking why the script was giving him problems. I prefer to explain the problems instead of writing the correct code for him.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I did try to 'read' which answer had been clicked, previously, but my script still is not working as intended. I can give vbariable x to the index of the answer that's clicked, and variable y is the value it should be (ie the number generated randomly). I say if x == y do this, but it's not behaving properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I appreciate it, but I'm gonna use data instead of text as previously suggested.